# Applescript to open safari with osescript and specific URL

Tags: safari, applescript

I am trying to run the following script:

```
on run proUrl
    tell application "Safari"
        make new document with properties {URL:proUrl}
    end tell
end run
```

This is how I try to run it: `osascript script.scpt http://google.com`.
I receive the following error:
`script.scpt: execution error: Safari got an error: AppleEvent handler failed. (-10000)`
In case I substitue the `proUrl` variable to `"http://google.com"` then it works.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

proUrl is a list of items, even if there's only 1 item you are sending to the applescript. So the actual url is "item 1 of proURL". Here's how I would write your script...

```
on run proUrlList
    open location (item 1 of proUrlList)
end run
```

Answer (score 0):

To open a URL in your default browser from the command line, just use `open`:

```
open http://google.com
```

See `man open` for more.

Comment: This does not answer the OP question of how to launch Safari specifically. This will not launch Safari unless Safari is the default browser.